# What's the best way to let a user pick a subdirectory in C#?

Tags: c#

What's the best way to let a user pick a subdirectory in C#?

For example, an app that lets the user organize all his saved html receipts.  He most likely is going to want to be able to select a root subdirectory that the program should search for saved webpages (receipts).

Duplicate:

- [Browse for a directory in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767/browse-for-a-directory-in-c)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Folder Browser Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) is the way to go.

If you want to set an initial folder path, you can add this to your form load event:

```
// Sets "My Documents" as the initial folder path
string myDocsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = myDocsPath;
```

Answer (score 7):

Check the [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) class.

```
// ...    
if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) works just fine for this purpose.

Comment: you guys should either expand or delete ... its the same as CMS's answer

Answer (score 2):

FolderBrowserDialog works, but offers very little customization.

If you want a textbox where users can type in the path [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576741/customising-the-browse-for-folder-dialog-to-show-the-path)

Dupe of: 
[Browse for a directory in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767/browse-for-a-directory-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, don't use the `FolderBrowserDialog`.

Just kidding.  Use that.

Comment: -1, really come on ... if you want jokes put them in comments

Comment: +1, really, come on. I think anyone with a basic grasp on english would understand what the poster meant.

Comment: I should just go about posting jokes on stack overflow and farming for rep, useful content who needs that