# Selecting Directory via Explorer on Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, explorer

I have a pretty simple question, i'm running a peer2peer service via a Console Application, I was wondering if I could simply open Windows Explorer, select the folder for my directory of Host Files and open another Windows Explorer and select another folder for Receiving Files.

Is this possible, keep in mind I don't think I am able to use STAThread because the peers are inherently multithreaded.

Right now, i'm using

```
Process.Start(@hostDirectory);
```

to simply browse where I am, but I want to make it easier on the user via Windows explorer.

Comment: Are looking for the [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @rinukkusu I think this might be exactly what i'm looking for. If so thanks in advance!

Comment: @rinukkusu hmm, seems like I cannot use System.Windows.Forms where it is based in. Strange, I'll keep looking though.

Comment: You probably have to add a Reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll.

Comment: You can find your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270387/browse-for-folder-in-console-application

Comment: @SebastianSchulz thank you, found what i was looking for